# Hibernate Criteria contains-in on an association to a table

Tags: hibernate, criteria, contains, scalar

I have a Hibernate mapping that looks something like this:

```
<class name="MyEntity">
  <set name="scalarSet" table="(select fk, scalar_value from other_table)">
    <key column="fk"/>
    <property column="scalar_value" type="long"/>
  </set>
</class
```

Given this, how do I query such that a value of MyEntity.scalarSet (which is Set) is in a another collection.

Something like:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("scalarSet", targetList));
```

[edit]
I've also tried Restriction.sqlRestriction(..). The sql query that I used is something like this:

```
"1 == (select fk, scalar_value from other_table where fk = {alias}.id and scalar_value in ({expanding?})"
```

Wherein '{expanding?}' is replaced by comma-separated question marks (depending on targetList.size()).

But I'm just getting a

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association: MyEntity.scalarSet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set is a collection, not an association mapping - there are subtle but important differences. Using Hibernate's Query API for collections is currently [not supported](http://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A2).

You need to either use HQL, or use a one-to-many association mapping by creating an entity with Long property, for example:

```
public class Scalar {
  private Long value;
  public Long getValue() { .... }
  public void setValue(....) { ....}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after hacking around with hibernate's source, this is what I ended up doing :-)

Answer (score 2):

However, someone has written a [patch](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2008-December/003542.html) which may or may not end up in Hibernate 3.4