# How do I query for objects with a value in a String collection using Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: hibernate

Let's say Student is the parent class in an inheritance hierarchy that includes ComputerScienceStudent and ITStudent.  Student defines a field called favoriteColors, which is a value-typed collection of Strings.  Using the criteria API I'd like to query for all students who list "blue" as one of their favoriteColors.

Here is the relevant java snippet

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class Student {

    @CollectionOfElements
    Set<String> favoriteColors = new TreeSet<String>();
```

I looked at the hibernate documentation found at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html and it looks like something like this might be a start

```
List students = sess.createCriteria(Student.class)
.createCriteria("favoriteColors")
    .add( Restrictions.eq(??????, "blue") )
.list();
```

but I don't know what to fill in as the name of the property since String is not a class I defined (thus the ??????)

I'd really like to avoid using HQL unless there is absolutely no way to do this using criteria. I'd also like to avoid adding sqlRestrictions.  I don't think the example API will work because Student is the abstract parent class in an inheritance hierarchy and I can't create a concrete Student to pass in as an example.

Is this possible?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried writing

```
List students = sess.createCriteria(Student.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("favoriteColors", "blue") )
.list();
```

Edit: Ok, that doesn't work. According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303157/hibernate-criteria-contains-in-on-an-association-to-a-table), refering to elements of value-type collections is currently impossible using the Criteria API.

Comment: Just did, it fails with the message ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Parameter #1 is not set

Comment: I see. Edited to include that - and I found a related question that hopefully helps.

Comment: That's bad news.  But thanks. At least now I know not to keep pursuing this path until hibernate gets this functionality.