# Java Hibernate Projections.sqlGroupProjection aliasing

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, projection

I have a `Criteria` using Hibernate like this

```
public class Student
{
    private Integer id,discriminatorColumn,discriminatorValue;
    //other stuff omitted for brevity
}
```

This entity has a `discriminatorColumn` which have values from 1 to 10 (never `NULL`) and each `discriminatorColumn` has a `discriminatorValue` which have a value from `1 to 100` (never `NULL`)

Example: (Student data)

```
ID DiscriminatorColumn DiscriminatorValue
1            1                  3
2            2                  4
3            1                  13
```

And so.

I am trying to get a `SUM` of the `DiscriminatorValue` grouping by `DiscriminatorColumn`

I mean, in the previous example if I filter by `DiscriminatorColumn = 1` I would receive `SUM=16`.

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
.setProjection(Projections.sqlGroupProjection(
    "sum({alias}.discriminatorValue) as rowCount",
    "hibernateAlias.discriminatorColumn having rowCount>0",
    new String[]{"rowCount"},
    Helper.HIBERNATE_INTEGER_INSTANCE
 ));
```

This creates the `rightSQL` I see something like this

```
select sum(discriminatorValue) as rowCount
from student
group by discriminator_column
having rowCount>0
```

The problem i have is when i set the `resultSetTransformer` to Student.class I could not find the way Hibernate populates the `sum` of `discriminatorValue` column result in `discriminatorValue` Java field.

I think that for that purpose is use the following parameter `new String[]{"rowCount"}`

But I have tried

```
new String[]{"discriminatorValue"}
new String[]{"this.discriminatorValue"}
new String[]{"{alias}.discriminatorValue"}
new String[]{"{studentAlias}.discriminatorValue"} using alias in Criteria
new String[]{"rowCount as discriminatorValue"} 
new String[]{"rowCount as this_.discriminatorValue"}
and So On..
```

But seems impossible what i am doing wrong? It's not possible? `Sum the values as set it as a simple Property as retrieving regular from database`.

I have written my own transformer for this but it's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
Projections.sqlGroupProjection("sum({alias}.discriminatorValue) as rowCount","hibernateAlias.discriminatorColumn having rowCount>0",new String[]{"rowCount"},Helper.HIBERNATE_INTEGER_INSTANCE)
```

Seems the `rowCount` aliasing in `new String[]{"rowCount"}` is just for MySQL syntax or is just ignore by `Criteria engine` is you need to use a alias to populate a property of your EntityClass use `outer alias instead`.

Example:

```
yourProjections.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("sum({alias}.discriminatorValue) as rowCount","hibernateAlias.discriminatorColumn having rowCount>0",new String[]{"rowCount"},Helper.HIBERNATE_INTEGER_INSTANCE),"discriminatorValue"));
```

Just wrap your `sqlGroupProjections` in a `Projection.alias` as set the alias match your property in your Java class and Hibernate will populate with the sum result and not `custom transformer are not longer required`.